# MySQL 1366 incorrect integer value

Tags: mysql, integer, mysql-5.7

I am trying to import a csv file into a MySQL DB.
Said csv file is from a select * from the same table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/import.csv' 
INTO TABLE fisc_hist_header 
character set utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(-- a whole lot of fields ...)
SET `CREATED_DATE`=STR_TO_DATE( @yourdatecolumn, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s' )
```

The file starts with

```
545752715002093599;3;1;503955117000124560;28/11/2019 14:38:51;0 -- all the other fields
```

What I get is [image]

After searching here, all results are for

Incorrect integer value: ''
What is different and strange to me is that for me, it gets the value but does not inputs it as an integer ?

EDIT : As asked here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `fisc_hist_header` (
  `fiscal_idx` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invc_sid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sbs_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_no` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `workstation_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `invc_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cashier_name` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `associate_name` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_code` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_address1` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_address2` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_address3` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_address4` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_address5` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_address6` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_zip` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_sid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_title` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_last_name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_first_name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address1` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address2` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address3` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_address4` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_zip_code` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_country` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_phone` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_email` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_count` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `grand_total_receipt` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `prism_version` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `plugin_version` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag_first_record` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `signature_key` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `signature` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `signature_previous` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `signature_short` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fiscal_idx`),
  UNIQUE KEY `un_fhh` (`invc_sid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=364 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: That's a very big number for an integer what is the column data type?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) for integer values, the maximum value for an unsigned integer which can be held in an `INT` column is `4294967295`. For a standard signed integer it's `2147483647`.

Your number `545752715002093599` is larger than both of these. You'll need to declare the target column as `BIGINT` in your `fisc_hist_header` table - the max value for a signed integer in this column type is `9223372036854775807`.

These restrictions exist because of the number of bytes used by MySQL to store each value in the database. If you know you won't need to store values above a certain limit, you can use a smaller integer type in order to save disk space and memory.

Comment: You are right that it is too big for an integer. Though, it does not work better if I input just a 3 for exemple, also the field is actually a bigint(20) in the table (and the data was exported from this same table, so I think the problem comes from somewhere else ...

Comment: Hmm. Can we see a generated CREATE TABLE statement for this table then, please.

Comment: Added in Question Edit (too big for comments)

Comment: Strange. I made a minimal demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a795263d6c067b7993ab77ba06d543cf , and there's no problem with the values. Obviously I had to use an INSERT instead of LOAD DATA but the point is that the values are acceptable. That at least narrows the problem down to potentially being related to the LOAD command. I'm not so familiar with that tool, but maybe someone else with more expertise will be able to help